# Detectar cadena en un texto y devolver los datos coincidentes. Python

Tags: python, programación-funcional

Quiero crear una función a la que le pase un argumento y que me busque en un archivo csv las cadenas que se correspondan con el argumento.
El archivo tiene la siguiente forma:

```
    Rank,Name,Platform,Year,Genre,Publisher,NA_Sales,EU_Sales,JP_Sales,Other_Sales,Global_Sales
1,Wii Sports,Wii,2006,Sports,Nintendo,41.49,29.02,3.77,8.46,82.74  
2,Super Mario Bros.,NES,1985,Platform,Nintendo,29.08,3.58,6.81,0.77,40.24  
3,Mario Kart Wii,Wii,2008,Racing,Nintendo,15.85,12.88,3.79,3.31,35.82  
4,Wii Sports Resort,Wii,2009,Sports,Nintendo,15.75,11.01,3.28,2.96,33  
5,Pokemon Red/Pokemon Blue,GB,1996,Role-Playing,Nintendo,11.27,8.89,10.22,1,31.37
6,Pokemon Diamond/Pokemon Pearl,DS,2006,Role-Playing,Nintendo,6.42,4.52,6.04,1.37,18.36
7,Grand Theft Auto V,PS3,2013,Action,Take-Two Interactive,7.01,9.27,0.97,4.14,21.4
```

La función que he intentado crear sería la siguiente:

```
def filtra_por_saga(juegos, saga):
    result = {i.name for i in juegos if i.name.split()[0] == saga}
    return result
```

Donde juegos es el archivo de lectura y saga sería la cadena de caracteres para filtrar. Trabajo con namedtuple y la función debe devolver el nombre completo del videojuego si una parte de este se corresponde con el argumento dado. Ej: Si saga es "Grand theft autos", la función debe retornar todos los nombres de videojuegos que contengan esa parte en él ("Grand theft autos IV","Grand theft autos V",etc). El problema que tiene la función que he creado es que solo funciona con argumentos que no sean compuestos; ej: (saga = "Pokemon", retorna "Pokemon Red/Pokemon Blue", etc).

La función para testear es la siguiente:

```
def test_filtra_por_saga(juegos, saga):
    print(filtra_por_saga(juegos, saga))
test_filtra_por_saga(juegos, "Pokemon")
```

La cadena de comparación variará a través de 'test_filtra_por_saga(juegos, " ")'. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu función

```
def filtra_por_saga(juegos, saga):
    result = {i.name for i in juegos if i.name.split()[0] == saga}
    return result
```

estás verificando que, tras dividir el campo `.name` por los espacios, si te quedas con el primer elemento éste ha de coincidir con el parámetro `saga`. Por tanto sólo te aceptará coincidencias si la primera palabra es exactamente la suministrada. Pero si `saga` vale por ejemplo `"Grand theft autos"` nunca se producirán coincidencias ya que la primera palabra del nombre nunca podrá ser `"Grand theft autos"` (si acaso, podría ser `"Grand"`.

Quizás más parecido a lo que tú intentabas sería esto:

```
def filtra_por_saga(juegos, saga):
    result = {i.name for i in juegos if i.name.startswith(saga)}
    return result
```

En el que no dividimos `.name` para quedarnos con la primera palabra, sino que verificamos si *comienza por* la cadena especificada en `saga`.

Aún así, no creo que esto cumpla con la especificación pues ¿qué pasa si `saga` vale `"Auto"`?  ¿No debería también devolver `"Grand Theft Auto V"`, etc.? Es decir, creo que con que la palabra en `saga` aparezca en cualquier lugar del nombre, debería devolverlo.

Con este cambio ya lo haría:

```
def filtra_por_saga(juegos, saga):
    result = {i.name for i in juegos if saga in i.name}
    return result
```

Finalmente un par de detalles:

- Si quieres que lo encuentre sin importar que esté en mayúsculas o mínúsculas, puedes usar `.lower()` para pasar a mayúsculas tanto `saga` como el nombre antes de verificar si está contenido.
- Veo que has usado una expresión un tanto rara para acumular los resultados, y es usar un generador entre llaves. Esto te creará un *conjunto* (tipo de datos `set()`) que es una especie de lista en la que no pueden haber datos repetidos. No creo que sea eso lo que buscabas, pues de todas formas ya que en cada iteración estás sacando un nombre diferente no iban a ocurrir repeticiones de todas formas. Yo cambiaría las llaves por corchetes para retornar una lista normal en lugar de un conjunto.

Aplicando ambos cambios:

```
def filtra_por_saga(juegos, saga):
    result = [i.name for i in juegos if saga.lower() in i.name.lower()]
    return result
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, funciona correctamente. Y lo del conjunto era porque en el archivo hay miles de videojuegos, y el mismo está disponible en distintas plataformas, lo que hace que aparezca varias veces. Y una pregunta, ¿no habría que poner un if entre ambos in?

Comment: @Jesus_jbs Sí, tienes razón. Ya lo he arreglado

Comment: @Jesus_jbs Si pueden aparecer nombres repetidos y quieres evitarlos, entonces tu expresión entre llaves estaba correcta. Pero aún así, en ese caso yo haría `return list(result)` para retornar el resultado en forma de lista, que puede ser más útil para quien la reciba (por ejemplo, podrá ordenarla por orden alfabético)